# How to access a child class method from a parent class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

There are a lot of answers saying this is unadvisable, but I found a scenario where I think it's useful. Please correct me if I'm wrong and there's a better way.

I'm building a chess game, where individual pieces inherit from the superclass `Chesspiece`:

```
class ChessPiece:
    def __init__(self, pos, color, num, piece):
        ...
```

Each piece has a method that defines the moves it can take:

```
class Knight(ChessPiece):
    def __init__(self, pos, color=None, num=''):
        ChessPiece.__init__(self, pos, color, num, self.__class__.__name__)


    def possible_moves(self):
        pos_moves = []

        # Up, Right (1 space, 2 spaces)
        try:
            if 1 <= self.x + 2 <= len(Config.board) and 1 <= self.y - 1 <= len(Config.board):
                if Config.board[self.x + 2][self.y - 1] == '___':
                    pos_moves.append(f'{Config.tile_convert(self.x + 2)}{Config.tile_convert(self.y - 1, True)}')

        except Exception: pass

        #Up, Left
        ...

        return pos_moves
```

I'd like to implement a `move()` function. The code for the `move()` function will be the same for each piece, except for the fact that it has to compare the suggested move with the possible moves, which vary for each piece. I could make a `move()` function for each piece, but that would just be repeating code 6 times.

So, I'd like to define `move()` in `Chesspiece` and reference each piece's `possible_moves()` function.

Comment: What makes you think you need to do anything special? Just call the method. (You can define an [abstract method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) in the base class if you want, and it'd probably actually help, but you don't need to.)

Comment: If you initialize a`Knight` instance, it will have the `move()` and the `possible_moves()` method. So there is no problem. You might want to implement a dummy `possible_moves()` that just raises `NotImplemented` in the base class to prevent your IDE to complain.

Comment: Also, that `except Exception: pass` is a terrible idea. That kind of thing just hides bugs. Don't fall into that trap.

Comment: if the piece can't move it raises an exception, sometimes. Are you suggesting I use the specific exception that it raises? Because there's nothing else to do other than pass if an exception does occur.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to raise or catch exceptions in `possible_moves`. Raising an exception for invalid moves should happen in `move`, not `possible_moves`, and `possible_moves` should never interact with such an exception.

Comment: This seems to be the kind of problem which abstract classes were intended to solve.

Comment: if the exception is triggered the move isn't appended to `possible_moves`. That's the point of it

Comment: You shouldn't be raising an exception for that. Just don't append the move to the list.

Comment: I check if the move can be appended by seeing if an exception is raised when I try

Comment: Appending a thing to a list won't raise an exception. The code you've posted checks move validity with `if` statements. (There doesn't seem to be any handling for captures or for whether a move would leave the king in check, by the way.)

Comment: it will when tile_convert goes out of bounds. I haven't implemented king yet, but yes that's a good observation

Comment: I get what you're saying though, there must be an error in my logic for it to get to that point

Comment: Not to drag this conversation out longer, but I realize I implimented try except because if the indeces go out of range for the board it'll raise an `IndexError`. I'll just check for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler to implement an empty `possible_moves` in the parent:

```
class ChessPiece:
    ...
    def possible_moves(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def move(self, pos):
            if pos in self.possible_moves():
            ...
```

Or even return an empty set of movements in the parent class:

```
def possible_moves(self):
    return set()
```

But I think the first is better, so it forces all subclasses to implement it in order to been useful.

Comment: But the possiblemoves algorithm varies for each piece

Comment: That is why you need to implement it for each piece @alec_a

Comment: This is possible, but not actually necessary. Also, the exception is `NotImplementedError`. `NotImplemented` is what an operator overload method is supposed to return when it doesn't understand its arguments.

Comment: @Netwave oh, I understand now. You can just call the method using `self`.

Comment: What's the point of defining it in the superclass and raising an error if called?

Comment: @alec_a, the method will be there but it will warn you that it is not implemented instead of just telling you that it does not exist.

Comment: @Netwave: Which... isn't really an improvement.

Comment: @user2357112, Yeah, the solution is jus to implemente the method and use it. However he handles whether or not it is implemented is up to him.

Comment: I actually receive an error when I feed self as an argument to `self.possible_moves()`. on my end it works correctly without the `self`

Comment: @alec_a, that shouldnt be there indeed. Fixed it.